# OLAP difference between ORACLE and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, olap, rollup

I'm beginner  in OLAP manipulation in ORACLE. What is difference of OLAP between SQL Server and ORACLE?

Information I've understood about OLAP:

- In ORACLE, OLAP is represented logically in data warehouse by relational table with join. We can use T-SQL to query data in OLAP, ORACLE adds ROLLUP, GROUPING, ... in T-SQL to enforce OLAP operations.
- In SQL Server:

  - Like ORACLE, OLAP can be represented logically by relational tables with join, we can use T-SQL with ROLLUP, GROUPING SET, GROUP BY, ... like ORACLE to query data.
  - OLAP in SQL Server can be stored physically in SSAS, in this case, MS offers MDX to query data in OLAP.

So to learn OLAP in ORACLE, I can use the first option of SQL Server as an alternative (For the moment I have some difficult about material with ORACLE installation)

Thank for any suggestion or confirmation about my information.

Comment: If I understand your question, [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_OLAP_Servers) can be useful ;).

Comment: Oracle's Advanced Analytics option (chargeable extra licence) includes physical OLAP cubes.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/OLAUG/toc.htm)